# Adobe Photoshop 6.0 - Can you see the EXACT pixel position?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel-grid

Got a little question.  I'm using an older Photoshop and I apologize for that but I have to make due with what I have.

In Paint Shop Pro, you can click into an image and the exact pixel coordinate appears at the bottom, making it easy to know where, say, the center of the image is by the coordinates:

[image]

For instance, #1 is my cursor and #2 is the exact pixel coordinates of my cursor inside the image I'm editing.

Does anything like that exist for Photoshop 6.0?  Note: this is *not* CS6, it's just 6.0 (released in 2000, I believe).

Comment: This link shows a similar question with a few more options you might like to know exist (its CS5, but I think the options are about the same) http://superuser.com/questions/459216/how-to-get-exact-position-of-a-ruler-guide-in-photoshop/573629#573629 but more important, and the reason for posting, is that I saw the picture of the LDS building in SLC in your pic, and just wanted to comment on it ;-)

Comment: @BillyNair - Good eye!  :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be difficult to find many using 1999-2000 software today.

I believe Photoshop 6.0 had the **Info Palette** though. That shows the cursor coordinates. It'll be in the `View` or `Window` menu.

This is CC's panel, 6.0's palette will look similar. The x/y are coordinates for the cursor.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I see it.  Perfect!  Thanks a TON!  There's a Navigator tab that's open in that window by default, but when I click on the tab marked Info I can see the coordinates.